# Calculating Sugeno outputs

Tags: matlab, math, fuzzy

I cant figure out how MATLAB calculates the output value based on the inputs. I managed to work out how mamdami functions work (through area and centroids) however I cant fathom how to calculate the output.

The below link does give the formula but I dont understand how to apply this...all of the weights are 1 and this system currently has three rules.

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/fuzzy/fp49243.html

Help would be appreciated

Comment: If you're just looking to implement this you could look at: http://peach.googlecode.com/hg-history/57ba849f483dd801571d94c97260e8998f8a6ee4/doc/ref/html/peach.fuzzy-module.html.  However, I am not sure where your confusion is, and the weights of the system don't appear to be fixed at one.

Comment: was wondering how you're coming along with this issue, I'd be very interested to know how it turns out.

Comment: Im getting further, I will post the answer when I have it working. I know how to use the formula for one input, its when there are two there is an issue